# Push service implementetion on Android devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

First of all, I know GCM service and I have questions about it too.

If I want to implement a push service, is this the right way; Server waits for connections, Android client connects server and waits for data all the time. So server can send data anytime. Connection is always open with keep alive messages.

About GCM;

- Is GCM uses this logic?
- Is GCM works on all Android devices? I mean is it guaranteed that if a device using Android OS, it also supports this Google service?
- If GCM is not a guaranteed service on Android, how should I handle the case that there is no GCM support on device. Or is this a negligible case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is GCM uses this logic?

Generally yes, though bear in mind that there are a lot more details.

> is it guaranteed that if a device using Android OS, it also supports this Google service?

No. It is only going to be on devices that legitimately have the Play Store and the rest of Google's proprietary app suite. It will not be on the Kindle Fire, the OUYA, or other devices that are using Android purely from the open source project.

> how should I handle the case that there is no GCM support on device

Amazon has a GCM equivalent for the Kindle Fire series, IIRC.

Beyond that, since GCM is not a guaranteed delivery service, you need a fallback plan even for "normal" Android devices.

For example, let's suppose that you are writing an app to show news headlines to the user. In the absence of any push notification, you poll for new headlines every four hours, or when the user presses a "refresh" button in the UI. With GCM, your server can push down headlines as they arrive, which your app can pick up. This gives users on "normal" devices fresher data, but still covers cases where you miss some GCM messages or for devices that do not support GCM.

Answer (score -2):

Adding to what CommonsWare mentions about GCM, you may want to look at MQTT as another pub/sub mechanism; It works on any device that can run Java. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504761/gcm-alternative-for-local-networks-or-sending-messages-to-device-ip/17504849#17504849) is a link where I try to explain how it works.

That links applies to LAN messaging but it works over the internet as well. It is the mechanism that the Facebook chat app uses. On that link you will find another link to a git where I show MQTT in use on a simple home automation project. If you have any questions, I can try to answer them.